# Where can I ask a question on how to access the ceiling of an indoor swimming pool?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need help figuring out where it would be acceptable to ask this question. This is such a weird question that it doesn’t fit anywhere that I can determine.

Engineering SE?

> How is the ceiling of an indoor swimming pool accessed, if repairs
>   need to be done to anything up there?
>
> [image: ceiling of indoor pool]
>
> I need to take this speaker down and repair it. It is located over an
>   irregular sloping floor between the shallow and deep end. This pool
>   will be drained in August for cleaning.
>
> This pool has a shallow end and a deep end, with a ramp that slopes
>   down from the shallow to the deep, with a diving board off to the
>   side, and so the slope itself is uneven from left to right across the
>   slope.
>
> Apparently some sort of platform is needed to level the slope so that
>   a ladder or scaffolding could be utilized on top of it.
>
> Also some sort of bracing is needed to keep the platform from sliding
>   down the slope. The only thing I can think of, would be a long pole
>   from the structure to the wall of the deep end.
>
> A one-time-use wooden frame structure could be built, but it would be
>   better if the platform could be adjusted and reused in different
>   locations across the uneven pool floor.
>
> Is there any sort of product or device that already exists, that is
>   capable of doing this job?

**EDIT in response to answers provided:**

I have posted this on the Home Improvement SE as recommended.

[How to access the ceiling of an indoor swimming pool, over the water?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/144010/how-to-access-the-ceiling-of-an-indoor-swimming-pool-over-the-water)

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at DIY.se, though this feels like a job for someone with the tools and knowledge to do so. Seems... potentially dangerous in many ways

Answer (score 5):

As [some have commented/voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313111/where-can-i-ask-a-question-on-how-to-access-the-ceiling-of-an-indoor-swimming-po/313118#comment1025804_313111) I think the most likely place for your question to be on-topic is the [Home Improvements Stack Exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com) which:

> is for contractors and (serious) DIY'ers.
>
> The core of this site is around parts of your home that are typically
>   included when you buy or sell it, the structure, utilities, and major
>   appliances.

Comment: What is the procedure for moving the question to the DIY SE? Can a moderator do that? Or do I need to delete this and re-create it there?

Comment: You won't be able to delete this because it has an upvoted answer so I think you should just ask a new question at that site.